# Is there always an algebraically independent set?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $E \subset F$ be a field extension. Is it true that there is always an algebraically independent set?

This should be true. But when I consider the case for one element, if $F$ is algebraic over $E$, then a single element cannot be algebraically independent.

Comment: A single element is transcendental iff it forms an algebraically independent set. So if the extension is algebraic, then there are no algebraically independent (over $E$) subsets of $F$.

Comment: But there is a theorem saying that a transcendence basis exists. Also, how to argue there is no algebraically independent set over 1 element?

Comment: If the extension is algebraic then the transcendence basis is empty. It is not true that there is no algebraically independent set with one element. For example, $\{ \pi \} $ is an algebraically independent set over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Is it true if every singleton is not algebraically independent, then any set is not algebraically independent? It does not seem to be obvious from the definition.

Comment: If $S$ is algebraically independent over $K$, then any subset of $S$ will be also. You don't have to use every relationship in the algebraic equations you try.

Comment: Is the empty set algebraically independent?

Comment: The empty set is always algebraically independent.